# prestashop products on top menu

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I am not very good with prestashop so i can not resolve my problem:

i need to creare a drop down menu with sub category and products (like image).

[image]

This is my situation, how you can you i have created sub-cat and now i need to show the products of categories, like first image. I have just searched in the web about any solution but i have not found it (or i have used worng keywords). i now this is possible because the first screen, is the demo of theme that i'm using:

[image]

Thank you in advance to spending time for me :)

Comment: Hi can you look at this link and tell me if this the menu you want? https://i.net.au/ . My menus are on left hand side with categories and subcategories

Comment: @Shrilekha nope :(, for example in your web site, when you expand Gaming and Games, it will show you all game, not game cateogory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for each category call `getProducts` method, it will give you all products inside category.