# prestashop navigation: list products in the sidebar

Tags: prestashop-1.5

I'm working on a small ecommerce site (only 2 products for now, but more to come in a near future) and trying to improve the navigation between products. (Prestashop 1.5.5.0)

Currently, someone who is viewing a product on the shop and wants to view another one has to come back to the homepage, and from there select the product she wants to see. That's far from ideal.

**Is there a way to list all available products in a sidebar block, so that visitors could switch from one product to another easily (one click)?**

I tried the "new products block" (by Prestashop), but apparently it won't display products that are considered too old, so that doesn't work. I also tried the "products category" module (also by Prestashop), but it will only show content when the visitor is viewing a product; ideally the products listing should be visible on any page of the site.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I suggest you want to do this by right way without hardcoding something in core (but it is possible too) and using modules, so you need to know two things:

1. Part of sidebars where can appears e.g. Categories module it is
   [hooks](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS15/Integrating+content+in+a+page+using+hooks) named 'HOOK_LEFT_COLUMN' ('HOOK_RIGHT_COLUMN' for right
   column) and in module you can operate it using `displayLeftColumn()`
   method.

But

2. Will hooks showed or not depends from page template (and in modules pages from value of 'display_column_left' property). You can
   check `header.tpl` file in default theme for 1.5.x and may see there
   `{$HOOK_LEFT_COLUMN}` appears without any conditions, so it will
   shows on all pages like home, categories, product etc.

From other side

If, for some
    reason, your theme do not use left/right column hooks possible to
    create `Category` object in `FrontController.php`, call
    `getProducts` method and assign result to smarty variable that you
    will can iterate in template like I answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32766784/prestashop-products-on-top-menu/)

OR

if you have sidebar on all needed pages, but do not see Categories module
    there, just check `Modules -> Positions` in backoffice, find
    Categories module in Left column bloc and then click on `Edit`
    button on the right side of module name, maybe some type of pages
    just excluded there.

Comment: Thanks for the help, I'll check this as soon as I can. I'm a bit surprised that such a simple functionality is not already provided by a module, though.

Comment: sorry, I faced with a lot of, do not remember exact names, try to google something like "prestashop megamenu" (but check before buying)